# WebRTC - onicecandidate is not called

Tags: javascript, typescript, webrtc

I'm working since hours to get my simple WebRTC thing running. But `onicecandidate` does not get called (Except the null candidate). Also, after accepting the offer the callee fires the `negotationneeded` event. I thought this should only happen after creating an offer. I read nearly every WebRTC example in the internet but I don't find my mistake.

The Event Handlers are only logging.

Init:

```
this.ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8443');
        this.pc = new RTCPeerConnection(this.configuration);


        var mediaConstraints = { audio: true, video: false };

        var self = this;  
        this.pc.onicecandidate = this.gotIceCandidate.bind(this);
        this.pc.onaddstream = this.handleAddStream.bind(this);
        this.pc.onremovestream = this.handleRemoveStream.bind(this);
        this.pc.oniceconnectionstatechange = this.handleICEConnectionStateChange.bind(this);
        this.pc.onicegatheringstatechange = this.handleICEGatheringStateChange.bind(this);
        this.pc.onsignalingstatechange = this.handleSignalingStateChange.bind(this);
        this.pc.onnegotiationneeded = this.handleNegotiationNeeded.bind(this);
```

Caller:

```
  if (!location.hash) { //the caller has a location.hash
        self.initiator = true;
        self.hash = self.createHash();
        this.ws.onopen = () => {

            this.localStream = new MediaStream();
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints).then((stream) => {
                //this.pc.onaddstream({stream:stream});
                this.localStream = stream;
                return this.pc.addStream(stream);
            }).then(
                () => {
                    return this.pc.createOffer();
                }).then(
                (desc) => {
                    return this.pc.setLocalDescription(desc)
                }
                ).then(
                () => {
                    let data = JSON.stringify({
                        'sdp': this.pc.localDescription,
                        'hash': this.hash,
                        'initiator': this.initiator
                    });
                    this.ws.send(data);

                    console.log("sdp send:" + data);
                }).catch(this.error);

        }

        this.ws.onmessage = function (msgRaw) {

            let msg = JSON.parse(msgRaw.data);
            console.log("recieved a msg for initiator: " + msgRaw.data);
            if (msg.sdp) {
                self.pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(msg.sdp)).then(
                    function () {
                        console.log("initiator remote location set")
                    }
                );

            }
            if (msg.ice) {
                console.log("got ice message for initiator" + msg.ice);
                self.setIceCandiate(msg.ice);
            }
        }
    }
```

Callee:

```
else {
        this.ws.onmessage = (msgRaw) => {
            console.log("recieved a msg for caller: " + msgRaw.data);
            let msg = JSON.parse(msgRaw.data);

            if (msg.sdp) {
                console.log("recieved a sdp for caller: " + msg.sdp.type + msg.sdp.sdp);
                self.pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(msg.sdp)).then(
                    (() => {
                        return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints);
                    })
                ).then(
                    (stream) => {
                        //hier stream handlen
                        this.localStream = stream;
                        return this.pc.addStream(stream);
                    }
                    ).then(() => {
                        return this.pc.createAnswer()
                    })
                    .then(
                    (desc) => {
                        return this.pc.setLocalDescription(desc)
                    }
                    ).then(() => {
                        var data = JSON.stringify({
                            'sdp': this.pc.localDescription,
                            'initiator': this.initiator, 'hash': this.hash
                        });
                        console.log(data);
                        this.ws.send(data);
                    }).catch(this.error);
            }
            else if (msg.ice) {
                console.log("got ice message for caller" + msg.ice);
                self.setIceCandiate(msg.ice);
            }
        }
        this.hash = location.hash;
        this.initiator = false;
        this.ws.onopen = function () {
            self.ws.send(JSON.stringify({
                'hash': self.hash,
                'initiator': self.initiator
            }));
        }
    }
```

Event HAndler:

```
handleAddStream(): void {
        console.log("handleAddStream");
    }


    handleRemoveStream(): void {
        console.log("handleRemoveStream");
    }

    handleICEConnectionStateChange(): void {
        console.log("handle ICE connection state change:" + this.pc.iceConnectionState);
    }
    handleICEGatheringStateChange(): void {
        console.log("handle ICE gathering state change: " + this.pc.iceGatheringState);
    }

    handleSignalingStateChange(): void {
        console.log("handle Signaling state change: " + this.pc.signalingState);
    }

    handleNegotiationNeeded(): void {

        console.log("handle negaotation needed");
    }
gotIceCandidate(evt:RTCPeerConnectionIceEvent) {
        console.log("onIceCandidate: " + evt.candidate);
        if (evt.candidate != null) {
            console.log("got ice candidate");
            this.ws.send(JSON.stringify({
                'ice': evt.candidate,
                'initiator': this.initiator, 'hash': this.hash
            })
            )
        }
    }
```

This is the log of the caller (logged in Opera Dev Tools Console):

```
handle negaotation needed
bundle.js:83572 sdp send:{"sdp":{"type":"offer","sdp":"v=0\r\no=- 1136332092735661893 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE audio\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS UAGAiTGJkol3ekmevak1bV3v5qAciinhzlKh\r\nm=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:AMaT\r\na=ice-pwd:kl8Hzi7+XMuD5KhcteFZKBPM\r\na=ice-options:trickle\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 32:F2:9A:92:09:8A:17:A6:52:20:88:01:FA:83:50:FC:6C:85:D0:51:1C:E4:81:88:36:C0:F6:34:F9:AF:20:10\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:audio\r\na=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2\r\na=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc\r\na=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1\r\na=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000\r\na=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000\r\na=rtpmap:9 G722/8000\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\na=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\r\na=rtpmap:106 CN/32000\r\na=rtpmap:105 CN/16000\r\na=rtpmap:13 CN/8000\r\na=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000\r\na=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000\r\na=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000\r\na=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000\r\na=ssrc:3433491845 cname:WBo9Ljf049MIHSUN\r\na=ssrc:3433491845 msid:UAGAiTGJkol3ekmevak1bV3v5qAciinhzlKh ad862009-7cc9-44a0-99f8-db76d6bf6d42\r\na=ssrc:3433491845 mslabel:UAGAiTGJkol3ekmevak1bV3v5qAciinhzlKh\r\na=ssrc:3433491845 label:ad862009-7cc9-44a0-99f8-db76d6bf6d42\r\n"},"hash":"b5fe2d","initiator":true}
bundle.js:83643 handle Signaling state change: have-local-offer
bundle.js:83640 handle ICE gathering state change: gathering
bundle.js:83640 handle ICE gathering state change: complete
bundle.js:83670 onIceCandidate: null
bundle.js:83577 recieved a msg for initiator: {"sdp":{"type":"answer","sdp":"v=0\r\no=- 6491298606329810899 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE audio\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS o7uVOFEMUCnV4NwOSj64rYW9E1FfFXBxxABe\r\nm=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:nVAM\r\na=ice-pwd:FuhqvuJNyzJosJbyoNjlRPnc\r\na=ice-options:trickle\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 3C:8D:2D:AE:29:D2:88:1E:D1:56:11:B9:EE:CC:2F:6D:D8:8E:41:71:ED:D2:6D:BC:79:FD:12:21:FA:C4:44:43\r\na=setup:active\r\na=mid:audio\r\na=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2\r\na=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc\r\na=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1\r\na=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000\r\na=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000\r\na=rtpmap:9 G722/8000\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\na=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\r\na=rtpmap:106 CN/32000\r\na=rtpmap:105 CN/16000\r\na=rtpmap:13 CN/8000\r\na=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000\r\na=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000\r\na=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000\r\na=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000\r\na=ssrc:1112390810 cname:P9L/gZVWuFwyyY7Y\r\na=ssrc:1112390810 msid:o7uVOFEMUCnV4NwOSj64rYW9E1FfFXBxxABe 26d25a55-d006-4b21-8219-5ad387146d52\r\na=ssrc:1112390810 mslabel:o7uVOFEMUCnV4NwOSj64rYW9E1FfFXBxxABe\r\na=ssrc:1112390810 label:26d25a55-d006-4b21-8219-5ad387146d52\r\n"}}
bundle.js:83643 handle Signaling state change: stable
bundle.js:83637 handle ICE connection state change:checking
bundle.js:83580 initiator remote location set
bundle.js:83631 handleAddStream
```

log of the callee:

```
recieved a msg for caller: {"sdp":{"type":"offer","sdp":"v=0\r\no=- 1136332092735661893 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE audio\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS UAGAiTGJkol3ekmevak1bV3v5qAciinhzlKh\r\nm=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:AMaT\r\na=ice-pwd:kl8Hzi7+XMuD5KhcteFZKBPM\r\na=ice-options:trickle\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 32:F2:9A:92:09:8A:17:A6:52:20:88:01:FA:83:50:FC:6C:85:D0:51:1C:E4:81:88:36:C0:F6:34:F9:AF:20:10\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:audio\r\na=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2\r\na=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc\r\na=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1\r\na=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000\r\na=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000\r\na=rtpmap:9 G722/8000\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\na=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\r\na=rtpmap:106 CN/32000\r\na=rtpmap:105 CN/16000\r\na=rtpmap:13 CN/8000\r\na=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000\r\na=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000\r\na=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000\r\na=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000\r\na=ssrc:3433491845 cname:WBo9Ljf049MIHSUN\r\na=ssrc:3433491845 msid:UAGAiTGJkol3ekmevak1bV3v5qAciinhzlKh ad862009-7cc9-44a0-99f8-db76d6bf6d42\r\na=ssrc:3433491845 mslabel:UAGAiTGJkol3ekmevak1bV3v5qAciinhzlKh\r\na=ssrc:3433491845 label:ad862009-7cc9-44a0-99f8-db76d6bf6d42\r\n"}}
...
bundle.js:83643 handle Signaling state change: have-remote-offer
bundle.js:83631 handleAddStream
bundle.js:83646 handle negaotation needed
bundle.js:83643 handle Signaling state change: stable
bundle.js:83611 {"sdp":{"type":"answer","sdp":"v=0\r\no=- 6491298606329810899 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE audio\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS o7uVOFEMUCnV4NwOSj64rYW9E1FfFXBxxABe\r\nm=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:nVAM\r\na=ice-pwd:FuhqvuJNyzJosJbyoNjlRPnc\r\na=ice-options:trickle\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 3C:8D:2D:AE:29:D2:88:1E:D1:56:11:B9:EE:CC:2F:6D:D8:8E:41:71:ED:D2:6D:BC:79:FD:12:21:FA:C4:44:43\r\na=setup:active\r\na=mid:audio\r\na=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2\r\na=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc\r\na=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1\r\na=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000\r\na=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000\r\na=rtpmap:9 G722/8000\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\na=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\r\na=rtpmap:106 CN/32000\r\na=rtpmap:105 CN/16000\r\na=rtpmap:13 CN/8000\r\na=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000\r\na=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000\r\na=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000\r\na=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000\r\na=ssrc:1112390810 cname:P9L/gZVWuFwyyY7Y\r\na=ssrc:1112390810 msid:o7uVOFEMUCnV4NwOSj64rYW9E1FfFXBxxABe 26d25a55-d006-4b21-8219-5ad387146d52\r\na=ssrc:1112390810 mslabel:o7uVOFEMUCnV4NwOSj64rYW9E1FfFXBxxABe\r\na=ssrc:1112390810 label:26d25a55-d006-4b21-8219-5ad387146d52\r\n"},"initiator":false,"hash":"#b5fe2d"}
bundle.js:83640 handle ICE gathering state change: gathering
bundle.js:83640 handle ICE gathering state change: complete
bundle.js:83670 onIceCandidate: null
```

Comment: I do not see where you're binding an event listener to `onicecandidate`…!?

Comment: I just did not paste it. I update the post

Comment: It would be rather pertinent, don't you think?

Comment: maybe. but i'm quite sure that it isn't the binding of the event. but I'm the one who is doing mistakes, so I updated the post. :)